# Assigning subjects to a student

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i am working on a student managment system project and i have a student,subject ,term and class models and i want to assign the subject objects to the student according tom the current term and class

```
class Subject(models.Model):
  """ Subject """
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  term = models.ForeignKey(AcademicTerm,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="subject-term",null=True,blank=True)
  student_class = models.ForeignKey('StudentClass',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="subject-class",null=True,blank=True)
  staff_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)



class AcademicTerm(models.Model):
  """ Academic Term """
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
  current = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)


class StudentClass(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
  term = models.ForeignKey(AcademicTerm,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)


class Student(models.Model):

    user            = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='student_profile',null=True,blank=True)
    group           = models.ForeignKey(Group,related_name='student_group',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    teacher         = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher,related_name="student_teacher", blank=True)
    parent          = models.ForeignKey('Parent',related_name="parent_sons",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    current_class   = models.ForeignKey(StudentClass, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="student_class", null=True)
    current_term   = models.ForeignKey(AcademicTerm, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="student_term", null=True)
    session_year = models.ForeignKey(AcademicSession, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student_seccion", null=True)
    subjects   = models.ManyToManyField(Subject,related_name="student_subject")

    def subject(self):
        term = AcademicTerm.objects.get(current=True)
        subs = Subject.objects.select_related('term').filter(term=term,student_class=self.current_class)
        for sub in subs:
            self.subjects = sub
        
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.subject()
        session = AcademicSession.objects.get(current=True)
        self.session_year=session
        parent = Parent.objects.filter(nationalId=self.parent_NationalId)
        if parent:
            self.parent = parent.get()
        return super(Student,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

is creating the subjects method and calling it in the save method right? or what?

Comment: you just needed to point to the AcademicTerm from the student model which you did.no need to declare functions.

Comment: is that meaning the subjects field isn't required ?

Comment: wait i have some due work.after i will try to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your models are not well arranged which can bring error during migrations, it would be better if your AcademicTem model come before Subject model and it could be good if you add DateField or DateTimeField to you AcademicTerm so that you can manage them according to the current date or time and retrieve subjects which have the same id as the current AcademicTerm and assign that subject to a student.